# How to convert the UTC date into local date in Moment.js?

Tags: datetime, timezone, momentjs

I have a date in this format "2020-12-16T02:48:00" that came from the server. How can I convert this into local date and time? I tried some code but couldn't succeed.

Below is the attempt that I had made in angular after receiving date from the server.

```
       response.data.map(date=>{
          var centralDate = moment( date).zone("-06:00");
          date = moment(centralDate).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
        })
```

Comment: "I tried some code but couldn't succeed." It's good that you've shown what you tried... but the only thing we know is that it didn't work. What actually happened? What did you do to diagnose it?

Answer (score 2):

If indeed the value is in UTC (as per the title of your question), and it looks like `"2020-12-16T02:48:00"`, and you want to convert it to *local* time, then you should do the following:

```
moment.utc(date).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

That does the following:

- Parses the input in terms of UTC
- Converts it to local time
- Formats it as a string in the given format

Note also that you had `hh` in your original format.  That is for hours in a 12-hour time format and thus you shouldn't use it without also using either `A` or `a` to indicate AM/PM or am/pm.  Otherwise `HH` is for hours in a 24-hour time format.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that the timezone doesn't change you can resolve using utcOffset (https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/) in this way:

```
 response.data.map(date=>{
      date = moment( date).utcOffset(-360);  
    })
```

Where 360 is the conversion fo the hours in minutes

Comment: I tried implementing the above logic by using  utcOffset. But it shows me the same result.

Comment: What do you need in particular, you need to pass this data to the interface? Or you need to process this data somehow?

Comment: I need to process this data and convert it into local time in order to display

Comment: Then you can use the subtract function like 'moment(date).subtract(6, 'h').toISOString()', this will return a string with the date you want

Answer (score 0):

var d= new Date();
d = new Date(d+ "Z")

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert in angular but I guess the trouble in your date is the word “T”.  May be using string removal function you can remove the word “T” and then it becomes a proper date time value?

Comment: The T is entirely inkeeping with ISO-8601... I'd be surprised if that were causing a problem.

Comment: @Ash even if I format the date, it will give me the UTC date i.e. 2020-12-16 2:48:00. instead of local date time. which is incorrect. The local date time is different from that of UTC data time. That's the main issue.